# Strip YouTube Embed Code Down to URL Only

Tags: php, youtube, embed, strip

Please help!

I need to strip the following code so that it only uses the "value" part

```
$<object width="360" height="226"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/IkZuQ-aTIs0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/IkZuQ-aTIs0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="360" height="226"></embed></object>
```

So in this case it would strip it down to http://www.youtube.com/v/IkZuQ-aTIs0

The catch is that this is dynamic so it is pulling these embed codes for different files so they are changing.

Please help :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = '<object width="360" height="226"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/IkZuQ-aTIs0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/IkZuQ-aTIs0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="360" height="226"></embed></object>';

preg_match_all('#http://www.youtube.com/v/([\w\-]+){11}#is', $string, $matches);

print_r( array_unique($matches[0]) );

?>
```

Comment: @Brad, I know. I'm not parsing HTML, just extracting URL. DOMDocument is overkill in this case.

Comment: Perhaps, but if it were me, I'd opt towards the standard solution, unless you could guarantee the input format.  DOMDocument won't be the fastest solution by any means, but if used correctly, you could traverse the document more reliably.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a DOM parser.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<object width="360" height="226"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/IkZuQ-aTIs0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/IkZuQ-aTIs0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="360" height="226"></embed></object>');
```

Comment: The VideoEmbed variable is what stores the YouTube Embed code that I'm trying to strip out. How can I add the code you all provided to this section if it is where I am supposed to add it? Sorry for the confusion I'm having a hard time displaying the code on here correctly I'm a noob

<?php if ($video['VideoEmbed']){
        echo "<a rel=\"shadowbox;width=700;height=400;player=swf\" href=\"" . $video['VideoEmbed'] . "\">View Video</a>";
       }?>

Comment: I made a new post that explains my problem better - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537550/rewrite-youtube-url

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<object width="360" height="226"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/IkZuQ-aTIs0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/IkZuQ-aTIs0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="360" height="226"></embed></object>';

$start = strpos($string, 'value="');
$string = substr($string, $start + 7);
$end = strpos($string, '" ');
$string = substr($string, 0, $end);

echo $string;
```

little more complex than webartos, but will grab any value, instead of just the youtube link

Comment: Thank you everyone for the fast feedback! I think I need to be more specific... basically the data for this is stored in XML format and I'm calling it like this
   [code]

Comment: Do not parse HTML in this manner.  What happens when you get to some broken HTML?  Let the standard classes built for this sort of thing do it, rather than re-invent the wheel.

Comment: And ive also had terrible luck with DOMDocument.... not really a big fan of that library