# How to convert youtube embed code to url?

Tags: php, html, youtube

There are a lot of examples of how to convert a youtube url to embed code, but I need a reverse code. I was never successful with all those expressions, so my question is **How can I convert an embed code to a URL** ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the src value from the iframe tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536787/strip-youtube-embed-code-down-to-url-only

Comment: I edited my answer, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can do that with [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get the `src` attribute of the `iframe`, and [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to convert it to the video url:

```
$embed = '<html><head></head><body><p>Hello, there is the video <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/K75a2k_6QWs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> what do you think?</p></body></html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($embed);

while($iframe = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('iframe')->item(0)) {
    $url = preg_replace(
        '~/embed/~', 
        '/watch?v=', 
        $iframe->getAttribute('src')
    );

    $iframe->parentNode->replaceChild(
        $doc->createTextNode($url),
        $iframe
    );
}

echo $result = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue; //'Hello, there is the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K75a2k_6QWs what do you think?'
```

Comment: Sorry, I have not mentioned, that there is some content around embed code and it must remain

Comment: @MindaugasJakubauskas so, do you just want to replace the iframe(s) with the video urls? Can you give an example of the string you need to get the url from and an example result string?

Comment: The example would be "Hello, there is the video *iframe* what do you think?" and the result should be "Hello, there is the video *video url* what do you think?" :)

Comment: everything works great, but somewhy I get all those http headers, how could I get rid of it? (I am using ajax $_POST, I know $_GET doesn't send those, but it is not really possible in my code.. )

Comment: @MindaugasJakubauskas What http headers do you mean? And are you sending the text with the `iframes` to `php` using `Ajax` to get them converted? If so, you could probably better convert them using `javascript` instead of using `Ajax` requests

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> <html><body><p>, no I'm sending it to write into database, convertion is just a little part of my code.

Comment: @MindaugasJakubauskas so if I get you right, you only want to parse the `HTML` inside the first `<p>` tag of the `body`?

Comment: @MindaugasJakubauskas it will now only parse and return the contents of the first `p` element in the `body`